# phpunit test for latest dependencies

Tags: php, unit-testing, continuous-integration, phpunit, travis-ci

**BACKGROUND**

I am working on a PHP project with unit testing and Travis CI. (It is [Source Speak](https://github.com/fulldecent/sourcespeak).)

This project "depends" on Twitter Bootstrap. In other words it includes the line:

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I can find out the latest release of bootstrap by querying:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/twbs/bootstrap/releases
```

**QUESTION**

How do I add a unit test that confirms that all URLs in the project like `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/*/css/bootstrap.min.css` are using the latest version of Bootstrap?

-and-

Is there any documented best practice that says I shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: You can use `Bower` to manage your frontend dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Yes, bower is a good solution as well and is probably preferable if you are already using bower for something else.

I would write a shell script that `curl`'s the version from the url and then downloads it from the version specified in the original curl call. There is no documented best practice that says you shouldn't be doing this, but I would probably add the bootstrap css file to version control so that you can track when you updated bootstrap and easily downgrade if a new version breaks anything.

If you need any help with the shell script let me know with a comment and I can show you one.